# What is the best method for executing multiple concurrent tasks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, task-parallel-library, asp.net-web-api2

I have been reading about the benefits of asynchronous programming. The advantages seem to be too great to continue to ignore it.  Thus, I decided to make a determined foray into land of asyncs, Tasks, and awaits.  I created a simple class to perform multiple concurrent POST operations to my Web Api.

Calling Method:

```
...

int tasks = 100;
for (var i = 0; i < tasks ; i++)
{
     int taskNumber = i + 1;
     var task = Task.Run(() => Post(taskNumber , address, client));
}

System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Task to be run:

```
private static async Task Post(int taskNumber, Uri address, HttpClient client)
{
        System.Console.WriteLine("Started Task#: {0}", taskNumber);
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var status = GetDeviceStatus();

        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<DeviceStatus>(address, status);
        sw.Stop();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Uri statusUri = response.Headers.Location;
            System.Console.WriteLine("{0}- Elapsed: {1} Path: {2}", taskNumber, sw.Elapsed, statusUri.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("{0}- Elapsed: {1} Path: {2}", taskNumber, sw.Elapsed, response.ToString());                
        }
    }
```

The code works as expected; however, is this the best way to perform this task (pardon the pun)? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think using task is the good approach to deal such issue.. I will say a good approach.. but remember the race conditions.. dont forget to make it thread safe.. else its perfect

Comment: Just because you put `threads = 100` it doesn't mean it uses 100 threads. All you did was instantiate 100 `Task` objects. How the TPL decides create threads and schedule the tasks is up to the TPL. It would be more accurate to call them `tasks` and not `threads`.

Comment: An issue you have with your code is that you are using the same `HttpClient` instance for all 100 tasks. The `HttpClient` object is not thread safe for calls to instance methods. You need to create a new client for each call.

Comment: Care for not mixing up parallelism and asynchronousity. You can boost yourself up with those operations run asynchronously, but even more, they can be invoked as a parallel group of tasks. Instead of a for loop, Parallel.For would imo feel suitable http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Enigmativity - Excellent point. I have made the corrections in my post.

Comment: @jmodrak: Thanks for the clarification. I will review the link provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) for I/O-based concurrency, and [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for CPU-based concurrency. Since a WebAPI call is I/O-bound, you should be using TAP and not TPL.

There's no need to call `Task.Run` in this case:

```
int requests = 100;
for (var i = 0; i < requests; i++)
{
  int taskNumber = i + 1;
  var task = PostAsync(taskNumber, address, client);
}
```

You could also use `Task.WhenAll` for a TAP-based join:

```
int requests = 100;
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, requests).Select(x => PostAsync(x + 1, address, client));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Also, `HttpClient` is mostly threadsafe. Details are on [its MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is to use the Microsoft Reactive Framework for this kind of parallel code rather than tasks.

Here's what I'd do:

```
var query =
    from n in Observable.Range(0, 100)
    from r in Observable.Using(
        () => new HttpClient(),
        client =>
            Observable
                .Start(() =>
                {
                    var status = GetDeviceStatus();
                    return new
                    {
                        Response = client
                            .PostAsJson<DeviceStatus>(address, status),
                        Status = status,
                    };
                }))
    select new
    {
        Number = n,
        r.Response,
        r.Status,
    };
```

As this is a query it doesn't get run until you call the query in some way. Here's how:

```
query.Subscribe(x =>
{
    /* Do something with
        x.Number,
        x.Response,
        x.Status,
    */
});
```

This is all handled on the thread pool. All of the synchronization is done for you. And I can get all of the results neatly returned as an anonymous object.

There is no perfect way to do this kind of thing but I like this approach.